# data-template-name issue in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

There is a strange issue am facing with ember.js, i.e when I add  "data-template-name" attribute to the script tag, **nothing is working**. If data-template-name name is removed, things are working fine.

```
  This is NOT WORKING 
   <script data-template-name="my-template"  type="text/x-handlebars">
    Input: 
    {{#view App.MyView}}
    {{view Ember.TextField 
           valueBinding="view.theValue"        
           placeholder="input ..." }}
    {{/view}}
</script>




  Now if **data-template-name="my-template"** is removed it works fine. 
I mean, In UI  TextField is visible.

  <script   type="text/x-handlebars">
    Input: 
    {{#view App.MyView}}
    {{view Ember.TextField 
           valueBinding="view.theValue"        
           placeholder="input ..." }}
    {{/view}}
</script>




App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
templateName: 'my-template',
theValue: null,
init: function(){
    this._super();
    this.set('theValue','asdf');
},
keyDown: function(e){
   if(e.keyCode === 13){
        alert(this.get('theValue'));
   }
}
```

});

Comment: With only thes samples, all I can suspect is that you have no defined view referring the "my-template" template. I guess the second case works because ember retrieve this anonymous template as the default template of your ember application. Providing more context to this question (javascript code), or even better a jsfiddle should help me to exactly tell you what's wrong

Comment: I have added JS view code.

Comment: ok I have added Js code! I have also created jsfiddle(Am not familiar with JS fiddle). Please forgive if anything goes wrong in this link http://jsfiddle.net/Yv5Bg/3/

Comment: sorry for beeing late, leaving work, food shopping, go back home, eat...and finally can code a little ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, don't worry about the jsfiddle, it's a good start :). There is a link on the ember.js site, where you can find a starting point, including Ember.js related sources: http://emberjs.com/community/

That beeing said, when creating an Ember.js application like this, there is an implicit default anonymous template, in wich you can then define yours.

```
 <!-- default template, introducing the view App.MyView -->
 <script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{view App.MyView}}
 </script>

<!-- template of App.View -->
<script data-template-name="my-template"  type="text/x-handlebars">
  Input: 
  {{view Ember.TextField 
         valueBinding="view.theValue"        
         placeholder="input ..."}}
</script>​
```

javacript:

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'my-template',
  theValue: null,
  init: function(){
    this._super();
    this.set('theValue','asdf');
  }
});​
```

Here is a working example of your sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/6p6XJ/171/

Comment: yes it works, But haven't mentioned what was wrong in my code!. I think accessing view by (App.view) was the problem or something else

Comment: Yes sorry, what was wrong was you were 1) not using the default template, and 2) using the view inside its own template